# Solution of a system of linear equation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am currently studying linear algebra and i have a problem with understanding the concept of consistent and inconsistent solution, what does it mean and when i know that my solution is consistent or not?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It's not the solutions themselves that are consistent or inconsistent; we use those terms to describe systems of equations. If a system of any number of equations has at least one solution, it's called "consistent;" if there are no solutions, it's called "inconsistent."

Take, for example, the following system:$$\begin{align} 2x+5y&=7\\x-2y&=5\end{align}$$

There are many different methods we can use, but they should all tell us that this system has a solution when $x=\frac{13}{3}$ and when $y=-\frac{1}{3}$. Because it has a solution, it's a consistent system.

For another example, consider this system:$$\begin{align}3x-2y&=8\\-6x+4y&=-16\end{align}$$

The second equation is simply $-2$ times the first equation, which means the two equations describe the same line. There are therefore infinitely many solutions, and this system is also consistent.

Finally, let's examine this system:$$\begin{align}-4x+2y&=3\\-4x+2y&=9\end{align}$$

Analytical methods will show that there is no pair of numbers $(x,y)$ that makes both of these equations true, and graphical methods will show that the lines represented by these equations never intersect. Therefore, the system has no solutions and is inconsistent.

Finally, all of these principles extend to systems of equations with any number of variables and any number of equations.